# trying to create a ipsec tunnel with ikev . :ubuntu machine: ip xfrm policy command executed but results shows no src and destination address

Tags: ubuntu, pki, tunneling, ipsec

On Ubantu machine I'm tying to Create the IPSEC tunnel
with below details:

```
sudo ip xfrm policy
```

src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0

```
 socket in priority 0
```

src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0

```
    socket out priority 0
```

src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0

```
    socket in priority 0
```

src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0

```
    socket out priority 0
```

src ::/0 dst ::/0

```
    socket in priority 0
```

src ::/0 dst ::/0

```
    socket out priority 0
```

src ::/0 dst ::/0

```
    socket in priority 0
```

src ::/0 dst ::/0

```
    socket out priority 0
```

when epsec statusall is executed

output :: sudo ipsec statusall

Status of IKE charon daemon (strongSwan 5.9.1, Linux 4.15.0-133-generic,
x86_64):

uptime: 22 seconds, since Feb 17 12:25:27 2021

malloc: sbrk 1482752, mmap 0, used 377952, free 1104800

worker threads: 11 of 16 idle, 5/0/0/0 working, job queue: 0/0/0/0,
scheduled: 0

loaded plugins: charon aes des rc2 sha2 sha1 md5 mgf1 random nonce x509

revocation constraints pubkey pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs8 pkcs12 pgp dnskey sshkey                      pem openssl fips-prf gmp curve25519 xcbc cmac hmac drbg attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default stroke vici updown xauth-generic counters

Listening IP addresses:

192.168.33.191

10.0.0.5

50.0.0.1

Connections:

```
  tunnel:  50.0.0.1...10.0.0.5  IKEv2, dpddelay=30s


  tunnel:   local:  [C=CH, O=strongSwan, CN=device1] uses public key
```

authentication

```
  tunnel:   remote: [C=CH, O=strongSwan, CN=device2] uses public key authentication

  tunnel:    cert:  "C=CH, O=strongSwan, CN=device2"

  tunnel:   child:  50.0.0.0/24 === 10.0.0.0/24 TUNNEL, dpdaction=restart
```

Security Associations (0 up, 0 connecting):

none::

dont understand why isnt the other side connecting as ipsec.conf  has been
set and also commands like ipsec pki has been executed and placed in /usr/local/etc/ipsec.d